# Event Listener not working even on chrome?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add event listener to my js but it doesn't works on chrome.  The error message by chrome is-

> main.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: numone.addEventListener is not a function
>   at main.js:6 (anonymous) @ main.js:6

```
var numone = document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box");
var numtwo = document.getElementsByClassName("feature-box2");
var addsum = document.getElementsByClassName("add-sum");

numone.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    alert("hii yash!");
}
, false);

//here's the HTML code(only the body tag)-

<body>
        <header>
            <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="location.html">location</a></li>
            <li><a href="contacts.html">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        </nav>
        </header>
        <section>
            <div><input class = "feature-box"></input></div>
            <div><input class = "feature-box2" /></div>
            <div><p class = "add-sum" ></p></div>
            </section>
            <footer>footer</footer>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: What is `numone` in your case? `addEventListerner` should be attached to `DOM` element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). We need more information to help you, but fundamentally, what the error tells you is that `numone` is not an `EventTarget` (that is, not an element or document).

Comment: Your updated question still does not mention anything about `numone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [getElementByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

So you can either assign it an ID and get it by ID or use `numone[0]`